# Maven build not finding custom jar already installed in local openshift project repo

Tags: maven, repository, local, openshift

I am facing an issue when trying to build my project (from the Eclipse Openshift plugin).

1.) I have a custom dependency, which at first I followed instructions on [Open Shift Knowledgebase Article "Using your own jar files..."](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1040-using-your-own-jar-files-in-a-java-application)

2.) On commit and publish with above, the error still persisted, thereby I changed the openshift pre_build action hook as noted in [this post on the Openshift forums "Resolved custom jar dependency..."](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/resolve-custom-jar-dependency)

However, I am still getting an error on commit and publish from eclipse. Here's a dump from the console

```
Repository ssh://53211e7...50000f0@testapp0...312-systix.rhcloud.com/~/git/testapp0...312.git/

Stopping RockMongo cartridge
[Sun Mar 16 12:20:37 2014] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd (no pid file) not running
MongoDB already stopped
Stopping jbossas cartridge
Repairing links for 1 deployments
Building git ref 'master', commit bb2def3
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/openshift/app-root/runtime/repo/shared-helper-data-skychart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /var/lib/openshift/53211e...0f0/.m2/repository/com/systix/shared-helper-data-skychart/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/shared-helper-data-skychart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.331s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 16 12:20:48 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/78M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/openshift/app-root/runtime/repo/shared-models-skychart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /var/lib/openshift/5321......00f0/.m2/repository/com/systix/shared-models-skychart/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/shared-models-skychart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.723s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 16 12:20:53 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/78M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn -e clean package -Popenshift -DskipTests'
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075437; 2011-06-20 13:22:37-0400)
Maven home: /etc/alternatives/maven-3.0
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-431.5.1.el6oso.bz844450.x86_64", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testapp0...312 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.134s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 16 12:21:04 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project testapp0...0312: Could not resolve dependencies for project testapp0...0312:testapp0...312:war:1.0: Could not find artifact com.systix:shared-helper-data-skychart:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/5321...00f0/jbossas

For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

On reviewing the above it seems like maven is able to add the dependency jars succesfully to the local repo ,but the build for the project does not seem to.

**UPDATE:** Including the pom.xml from both the libraries that I have marked as to be installed in the pre_build file. Both the jars were built, included in the openshift git repo, and referenced in the pre_build script to be installed in openshift's maven repo (pre_build script included at end)

pom.xml from shared-helper-data-skychart:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.systix</groupId>
  <artifactId>shared-helper-data-skychart</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.systix</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-models-skychart</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>0.105</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml from shared-models-skychart (shared-models-skychart is a dependency in the pom.xml for shared-helper-data-skychart)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.systix</groupId>
  <artifactId>shared-models-skychart</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>0.105</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

pre_build script used

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=../app-root/runtime/repo/shared-helper-data-skychart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.systix -DartifactId=shared-helper-data-skychart -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=../app-root/runtime/repo/shared-models-skychart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.systix -DartifactId=shared-models-skychart -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

**UPDATE 2:** Also, the above pom.xml is what I have in my project code files. However, when I ssh intoopenshift servers and review the local maven repos, the following is what I see as pom.xml

```
cat ./.m2/repository/com/systix/shared-helper-data-skychart/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/shared-helper-data-skychart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.systix</groupId>
  <artifactId>shared-helper-data-skychart</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show the full pom file of the project `com.systix:shared-helper-data-skychart:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: @khmarbaise : updates to my original post should provide the info

Comment: @khmarbaise, see further updates above

Comment: following my last comment, I was able to figure it out. If needed i can reshare, meanwhile time for me to goto bed :)

Comment: @user3423953 Yes, please reshare - could you post the answer? I'm having the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. I connected via SSH to OpenShift like described [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html).
2. There I found out that in the OpenShift maven repo (under ~/.m2/repository/) the jar had not been installed correctly. **In the dependency directory there were *.jar.lastUpdated files instead of the actual jars.**
3. I deleted the whole directory of the problematic dependency from the maven repo (manually)
4. In my pre_build action hook I changed mvn install:install -Dfile path to an absolute path to the jar (e.g. /var/lib/openshift/___your__id__here____/app-root/runtime/repo/dependencyfile.jar
5. I pushed my local changes (pre_build action hook changed in point 4.) to the git repo. Now all worked fine :)