# Including a custom JAR in Jbossas OpenShift app

Tags: java, openshift

I've been trying to follow the instructions for including a custom JAR file in my Java app on openshift. Here's a link to the instructions I'm following https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbossas-dependencies.html. These tell you to include the JAR file you need in the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ folder.

Unfortunately the deployed code is reporting a compile error because it hasn't included the JAR file in its build path.

I've seen a small number of other posts (e.g. [Maven build not finding custom jar already installed in local openshift project repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440312/maven-build-not-finding-custom-jar-already-installed-in-local-openshift-project)) about this problem that suggest a solution that involves installing the custom JAR file into the Maven repo and the referencing it through the pom.xml file. But they all refer to broken links on the OpenShift developer portal. In particular, this one https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1040-using-your-own-jar-files-in-a-java-application comes up a lot. But the link is broken, so they're all missing crucial context, or maybe they're out of date. Either way I'm struggling to follow them without the links.

**EDIT**

After following the link provided by Michael Dibbets below to an archived copy of the broken link I mentioned above I found some more instructions. If you follow the link you can see they tell me to use a pre_build file to install my Jar file to a maven repo. Unfortunately the address given in the instructions to reference the Jar file in the repo are incorrect. After a little fiddling I managed to get it to work by using the following instruction [mvn install:install-file -Dfile=../56e1739d0c1e665da800001f/app-root/repo/Test.jar -DgroupId=org.tfl -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar]. The string of numbers is the app name you can get from your web console or elsewhere. It's about as clear as mud for something so simple and Openshift's information about it seems to be absolutely incorrect (historic and present information).

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20140804113353/https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1040-using-your-own-jar-files-in-a-java-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do it would be to use an `EAR` project, but you can create a project repository as well, which is what you're asking.

1: Make a directory in the root of your project named `repo`.

2: Install your jar(s) there using maven install-file with the `-DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo` set to your repo directory. E.g:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar 
    -DgroupId=your.groupId 
    -DartifactId=your-artifactId 
    -Dversion=version 
    -Dpackaging=jar
    -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
```

3: Modify your pom file to use this local repo:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

4: Make sure it builds locally. You may want to clean out your project jars from your local .m2 repository and then build your project with `mvn clean verify` to insure the .war file gets built properly. After that it should deploy fine to `OpenShift` or `Heroku`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I managed to solve this in a simpler way after being provided an archived link to the old OpenShift help page by another user. But I can see that your way would benefit from having the local build work in a more similar way to the deployment build, I might try this in a little while.

Comment: Sounds good. I like the 'simpler" hack also, though I don't think I would have thought of that on my own. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a lib folder under \src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\ and copy custom jar file to lib folder. Finally it like this

```
\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\your-custom-jar.jar
```